# Adding a Numpy Array Variable to a Multidimensional XArray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have an xarray:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (gust_cat: 3, rose_group: 80, latitude: 726, longitude: 10020)
Coordinates:
  * gust_cat    (gust_cat) int64 1 2 3
  * rose_group  (rose_group) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
Dimensions without coordinates: latitude, longitude
Data variables:
    lat         (latitude, longitude) float64 34.14 34.14 34.14 ... 50.54 50.53
    lon         (latitude, longitude) float64 -111.8 -111.8 ... -88.06 -88.03
    ws10m_mean  (latitude, longitude) float64 5.2 5.293 5.863 ... 11.47 11.47
```

The values of ws10m_mean is an array of values:

```
[[ 5.20025411  5.29336974  5.86330838 ...  7.02323789  7.03675342
   7.38758065]
 [ 5.39607655  5.81841925  5.8054005  ...  7.00567918  7.00553018
   7.02013282]
 [ 5.80413771  5.79809436  5.78122711 ...  7.49698878  7.4709049
   7.44462379]
 ...
```

I want to use numpy percentile to get the 10th percentile of each array, keeping the dimensions of ws10m_mean and add this to the xarray as a new variable:

```
combined = combined.assign(ws10th_percentile = (['latitude','longitude'],np.percentile(combined.ws10m_mean,10)))
```

This process returns an error:

```
ValueError: Could not convert tuple of form (dims, data[, attrs, encoding]): (['latitude', 'longitude'], 7.291014076425293) to Variable.
```

Comment: Across which dimension do you want to compute the 10th percentile? You have 2D data - `np.percentile(combined.ws10m_mean,10)` will give you a single value which is the 10th percentile of all data points. You can for example compute the 10th percentile across longitude, then you end up with a 1D array, containing the 10th percentile over longitude for each latitude. What is it that you want to compute?

Comment: I want to compute the percentile for each grid point. Since each grid point in `combined.ws10m_mean` is an array the data is there to compute the percentile. In the end I want to add a variable to `combined` that is `percentile(latitude,longitude)`